# Get all the container logs using journald

Tags: containers, systemd, systemd-journald

I am using fluentbit for collecting logs and it allows filtering of systemd logs using journald by specifying a filter. eg - `--unit=docker.service` or `--unit=systemd*`.

I want to read **all the container logs**. I tried this to read the log of a single container as - `CONTAINER_ID_FULL=<container_id>`. This works. But using a regex like `CONTAINER_ID_FULL=*` doesn't work.

I tried to get a generic service for all the containers seeing if that helps. I ran `systemctl list-unit-files`. I was able to see my container running with (probably) a system unit name like `docker-<container_id>.scope`. So I tried using that as a service name with unit like `--unit=docker-<container-id>.scope` but this doesn't shows any data.

I ran `systemctl status docker-<container_id>.scope` (as suggested [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386211/relation-between-systemd-service-names-and-journald-entries)) to see if the service name was different, but it doesn't show any relevant info.

What I want is a way to get all the container logs using a single filter. Any help is appreciated.